# Copy grouped data (Entity) from Source Worksheet (protected) to another

Tags: excel, vba

i m new to vba and try to write some code copying some group data from a protected workbook to new Workbook.

In my source sheet is a list of grouped data with some columns like COUNTRY, REVENUE, WIN, LOSS. 
The entity of country is grouped by region. 
So under ever country is variable number of regions with subRevenue, subWIN, subLOSS.

What I expect: for a defined group of country entities (eg. GERMANY and JAPAN) I want to copy these data with its subdata (regions) to new Workbook.

May anyone provide me a generic example or useful functions?

Thank you in advance! (a VBA Noob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here something to start you off with.

First since the sheet is protected you'll need to unprotect it before being able to copy anything. The below code shows you how to do that and uses `strPassword` as a variable containing the password. Since the sheet is already protected in your case you'd start with unprotecting it, then doing your copying operation and then protecting it again.

In General you can use `range.copy` with `range.pastespecial` to copy data wherever you wish. To copy to a new workbook you can use `Workbooks.add` otherwise just specificy the filepath of the other workbook

```
Sub YourSub()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws =Worksheets("YourSheet")
Dim strPassword As String: strPassword = "YourPassword"
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add ' OR the workbook path

ws.Unprotect Password:= strPassword

  ws.Range("A1:AA100").Copy 
  NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  NewBook.SaveAs FileName:= ' Insert FilePath/  FileName here

ws.Protect Password:= strPassword
End Sub
```

This is some general information about how you would be going about copying ranges from a protected workbook to another workbook. To do this for certain countries you could create a table or use named ranges(using name manager or in VBA itself). Then you can adress the specific ranges either using `if.. elseif.. else.. end if` or the `select case` method, with your list of cases pointing towards a range containing all the countries to be copied.

Hope this was helpful as a quick overview